# Php- Eliminate characters while reading file

Tags: php, file

I would I am using PHP. I am reading from a file but I would like to eliminate the following characters from the file wherever they are: '' and { }.

I tried to use the trim function but the characters "',{ and }" are still present in the output:

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('out.txt');
$rows        = explode(",", $txt_file);
array_shift($rows);

foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode(':', $data);
    trim($row,"'");
    trim($row,"{");
    trim($row,"}");
    $info[$row]['state']          = $row_data[0];
    $info[$row]['action']         = $row_data[1];
    echo  $info[$row]['state'] . '<br />';
    echo  $info[$row]['action'] . '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: "but it is not working" is not a sufficient problem description. You may want to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include the desired behaviour.

Comment: Please do some research on `str_replace` and `preg_replace`. `trim` may not be a good idea for you since "{" and "}" may appear in the middle of your string. But right now your main problem is that `trim` does not function the way you are using it. `trim` returns the trimmed string, and you have to get it like this: `$row = trim($row,"{");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to remove `'` `{` and `}` from `$row`

If it is, then replace

```
trim($row,"'");
trim($row,"{");
trim($row,"}");
```

with

```
$row = str_replace(['\'', '{', '}'], '', $row);
```

**Note:** trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string. Moreover you didn't store trimmed data to any variable so literally you will not get trimmed data. `You want to replace characters wherever it is found` so use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`. Please check PHP manual for more details